# Use separate Enum Table(entity) in Entity Framework without join

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, enums

I have a entity Person which has an enum "State" with the values "new, accepted, blocked". Entity framework code first creates a field on the person table with an 1 for new, 2 for accepted and 3 for blocked. That's fine as long I'm in code view. Whenever I need to fix a db for what ever reason "1" doesn't mean anything, I need to look up first in code what 1 means for that enum.

My first idea was to simply make a separate table for those enums and make the enum a class with an id and the enum. But then I get another (unnecessary) join on each query where the enum is needed. I want to avoid that.

So, is it possible to have a separate table for the enum with fix ids so that the id of the enum table is equal to the value of the enum and still have entity framework using the normal approach where it just uses the value of the enum as saved value? I got stuck when I wanted to use a foreign key to enforce reference integrity to make sure no one forgets to update the enum table. Entity framework can't set this foreign key because it does not know the table and when it knows it, it makes relationships what I also don't want because of the joins..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years passed by, I learned a lot. So if anyone ever sees that question and wonders, here is what I normally do as of today.

So, unless there is a special reason to actually have a table for code (enum) values (like when you have additional data instead of just a code) I just put the enum value into the table that uses the enum. e.g. in the example above the person table gets a integer column for the enum value. In C# with entity framework I use it like this:

```
// write to db:
personEntity.PersonState = (int)State.New;
// read from db, e.g.:
if (personEntity.PersonState == (int)State.New {
  // logic here
}
// or if you need the value as enum:
State personState = (State)personEntity.PersonState;
```

I found that is a good and easy approach for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below

```
Module Module1
    Enum MyEnum
        a = 1
        b
        c
        d
        e
        f = 100

    End Enum
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As MyEnum = MyEnum.d
        Console.WriteLine(x)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
​
```